# Animate SKAction once before removing node

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm making a game and I'm implementing some stuff to happen in the didBeginContact function.

Basically, my guy throws a `projectile`, when that `projectile` connects, I need the `projectile` to disappear, the `enemy` it hit to perform an `animation` and then the enemy to disappear.

I can either get it so that the enemies animation plays through once and then disappears, but my projectile doesnt, or I can get the enemy and the projectile to disappear but no animation gets shown.

Here's my code so far:

```
if let node = contact.bodyB.node as? SKSpriteNode {

                if node.parent != nil {

                    let moveUp = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -100), duration: 0.5)

                    let fadeOut = RocketExp

                    let runBlock = SKAction.runBlock{ () -> Void in
                        node.removeFromParent()

                    }

                    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

                    let moveAndFade = SKAction.group([moveUp, fadeOut])

                    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, runBlock, remove])


                    node.runAction(sequence)
                    node.removeFromParent()
                }
            }
```

I'm pretty sure node.removeParent() just removes both of the nodes getting hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

```
let enemyCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let missileCategory:  UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory
enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = missileCategory 

missile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = missileCategory
missile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if body1.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory && body2.categoryBitMask == missileCategory{
       // your code here
       body2.node?.removeAllActions()
       body2.node?.removeFromParent()
   }
}
```